# Left join if value is in range between columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In BigQuery, I have a main table full of IP's (in decimal form) and I have another table that serves as an IP range blacklist. I want to check whether an IP belongs to the blacklist or not.

The problem is the blacklist contains IP ranges, so I have to check whether the IP in question is a value between the two range columns.

**Main ip_int_table**

| ip_int |
| --- |
| 12345678 |
| 22400006 |
| 22400005 |

**Second ip_int_blacklist_table**

| ban_id | from_ip_int | to_ip_int |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 12345678 | 22345678 |
| 1 | 22345679 | 22345680 |
| 2 | 22400000 | 22400005 |

**Result wanted**

| ip_int | is_banned |
| --- | --- |
| 12345678 | 1 |
| 22400006 | 0 |
| 22400005 | 1 |

This is the SQL I've tried, but I get an error that says I can't use left join without an equality of fields. (But I don't have any matching keys so I can't use equality).

```
SELECT
  ip.ip_int
FROM ip_int_table ip
LEFT JOIN ip_int_blacklist_table bl
  ON ip.ip_int BETWEEN bl.from_ip_int AND bl.to_ip_int
```

EDIT:
I tried the `UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(...))` solution but due to the large number of IP addresses a range can contain, I get the error "GENERATE_ARRAY... produced too many elements" (apparently BigQuery has an upper limit of 1048575 elements).

## Update 2021-08-24

So I realized I don't actually need the `ban_id`. I only need to know whether the IP is banned or not. Hence I've replaced the `ban_id` column in the output with `is_banned` (where 0 means false and 1 means true).

Comment: IPs will be `VARCHAR`. How do you say `int`. Can you show us sample data ? Dummy number is of no use

Comment: @IndraKumarS don't focus on the names and types :)

Comment: Your query works fine !!!! Whats your issue ? Check this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=edd0be3f4a2f2cd1bd7086bb1e544476

Comment: In BigQuery I get: "LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join."

Comment: @Nermin . . . Please tag. your question correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was the same !

Comment: @Nermin Its hard to help you without data. As far as i checked , everything is fine with your query. And here is the db fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=edd0be3f4a2f2cd1bd7086bb1e544476

Comment: By the way.... Is this not on Mysql ?

Comment: please tag question correctly.

Comment: @Nermin are you running these queries provided in solution or just making comments ? In my case there is no LEFT OUTER JOIN and you mentioned error related to LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it using a subquery and IF + MAX statement:

```
WITH
    ips AS (
    SELECT
        ip_int
    FROM ip_int_table),
    banned_ips AS (
    SELECT
        ip_int,
        MAX(IF (ip_int >= from_ip_int AND ip_int <= to_ip_int, 1,0)) AS is_banned
    FROM
        ip_int_blacklist_table,
        ips
    GROUP BY 1
)

SELECT
    ip_int,
    is_banned
FROM banned_ips
```

So the IF statement will either return 0 or 1 depending on whether it is a banned IP or not. The MAX is needed since we compare the IP against all ranges, and we only want to know if it matches *any* range.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
SELECT ip.ip_int, 
  (select ban_id from ip_int_blacklist_table 
    where ip.ip_int between from_ip_int and to_ip_int)ban_id
FROM ip_int_table ip
```

Comment: I get the error: "LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join."

Comment: No LEFT OUTER JOIN is used in this query. How can you get this error ? Can you explain more ?

Answer (score 0):

In BigQuery, you can expand out the values:

```
SELECT ip.ip_int, bl.ban_id
FROM ip_int_table ip LEFT JOIN
     (ip_int_blacklist_table bl CROSS JOIN
      UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(bl.from_ip_int, bl.to_ip_int, 1)) bl_ip_int
     )
     ON ip.ip_int = bl.bl_ip_int
```

Comment: I get the error: "GENERATE_ARRAY... produced to many elements". Probably because the ip ranges in my real data is too large

Answer (score -1):

```
select ip_int  from ip_int  ip
where exists
(select 1 from ip_int_blacklist  blk
where  ip.ip_int between blk.from_ip_int and blk.to_ip_int )
```

Comment: I get the error: "LEFT SEMI JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join."